# How to add quotes from specific delimiter to end of the line, using awk?

Tags: awk, line-endings

I am trying to modify a file: (file.txt)

```
abc~123~xyz~123456~12~0.12~14~1.1~  
omn~124~xdz~923231~13~0.0~13~1.1~14~0.45~19~80.1~
```

to (new_file.txt)

```
abc~123~xyz~123456~"12~0.12~14~1.1~"  
omn~124~xdz~923231~"13~0.0~13~1.1~14~0.45~19~80.1~"
```

I tried using awk command:

```
awk -F'~' '{for(i=1;i<=4;i++){printf "%s~", $i}; printf"\""} {for(i=5;i<=NF;i+=1){printf "%s~", $i}; printf "\"\n"}' file.txt > new_file.txt
```

but I am getting output as:

```
abc~123~xyz~123456~"12~0.12~14~1.1~~"  
omn~124~xdz~923231~"13~0.0~13~1.1~14~0.45~19~80.1~~"
```

Can anyone help me out in this as I am getting an extra "~" at end of each line? Any reference would also be helpful as I get confused while dealing with sed and awk commands.

Comment: Show output of this command: `file file.txt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `~` separator at the end of your lines. So, you have an extra empty field after this field separator. You can check this with:

```
$ awk -F'~' '{print NF "|" $NF "|"}' file.txt
9||
13||
```

See? When printing this last empty field followed by a `~`, you simply concatenate it to the previous one, thus the `~~`. Try:

```
$ awk -F '~' -vOFS='~' '{$5 = "\"" $5; $NF = $NF "\""; print}' file.txt
abc~123~xyz~123456~"12~0.12~14~1.1~"
omn~124~xdz~923231~"13~0.0~13~1.1~14~0.45~19~80.1~"
```

We just declare `~` as the input and output (with variable `OFS`) field separator, prepend a `"` to the fifth field, append one to the last field, and print.

Comment: Thanks @renaud-pacalet
Your solution is working for me but I don't need the first delimiter inside the quotes. It should be outside if you check the output I mentioned.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I should have better checked your expected output. Simply prepend a `"` to the fifth field instead of appending it to the fourth field. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program. Written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work in any `awk`.

```
awk -v s1="\"" '
match($0,/^[^~]*~([^~]*~){3}/){
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) s1 substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) s1
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, firstly creating an `awk` variable named `s1` which has value as `~` in it. Then in main program using `awk`'s `match` function to match regex `^[^~]*~([^~]*~){3}` which will basically match from starting of value to till 4th value of `~`. Once its matched, I am printing matched sub string(from starting of value to till 4th occurrence of `~`) then printing s1 and rest of the line's value followed by s1(as per OP's requirement).

---

---

***Additional solution:*** Assuming in case you have lines which don't match `~` condition( meaning doesn't have 4 times `~` in it and you don't want to add `"`) then use following:

```
awk -v s1="\"" '
match($0,/^[^~]*~([^~]*~){3}/){
  $0=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) s1 substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) s1
}
1
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

This `sed` will fairly simple solution for this:

```sh
sed -E 's/^(([^~]*~){4})(.*)/\1"\3"/' file

abc~123~xyz~123456~"12~0.12~14~1.1~"
omn~124~xdz~923231~"13~0.0~13~1.1~14~0.45~19~80.1~"
```

Similarly using `gnu awk`:

```sh
awk '{print gensub(/^(([^~]*~){4})(.*)/, "\\1\"\\3\"", "1")}' file

abc~123~xyz~123456~"12~0.12~14~1.1~"
omn~124~xdz~923231~"13~0.0~13~1.1~14~0.45~19~80.1~"
```

Answer (score 1):

And also with GNU `awk`:

```
awk '{sub(/~$/,"~\"");print gensub(/~/, "~\"", 4)}' file
abc~123~xyz~123456~"12~0.12~14~1.1~"
omn~124~xdz~923231~"13~0.0~13~1.1~14~0.45~19~80.1~"
```

- Two substitutions of the `~` by `~"`, one at the end with `sub()` and other at 4th apparition with `gensub()`.